# How to get records from SQLite in random order using the Sequel ORM?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel

Trying to convert this SQLite query

```sql
SELECT * FROM `terms` ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10
```

to work with a Sequel model. The closest I got:

```ruby
Term.order(rand{}).limit(10)
Term.order('random ()').limit(10)
```

which translate into

```ruby
<Sequel::SQLite::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM `terms` ORDER BY 0.6160215951854449 LIMIT 10">
<Sequel::SQLite::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM `terms` ORDER BY 'random ()' LIMIT 10">
```

but neither works. Is there a way to pass a SQLite- or other database-specific functions to Sequel's `order()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using a [**`Sequel.lit`**](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/SQL/Builders.html#method-i-lit) expression worked:

```
Term.order(Sequel.lit('RANDOM()')).limit(10)
```

Comment: You were pretty close with `Term.order(rand{}).limit(10)`. But you needed to pass it via a block, `Term.order { rand{} }.limit(10)`. In the current version, you'd use `Term.order { rand.function }.limit(10)`. See [virtual_rows.rdoc](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/4.36.0/doc/virtual_rows.rdoc#sqlfunctions---sql-function-calls).

Comment: @DwayneCrooks Calling `Term.order{ rand.function }` causes `Sequel::DatabaseError: SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: rand` since `rand` is not a SQLite function, but `Term.order{ random.function }` worked. Thanks for the hint.